# Google Maps, change the postal code on display

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I was wondering if I could edit the postal code of my google maps, as google maps has got the postal code wrong. I inspected the element and would like to change this line

```
<span jsattrs="dir:bidiDir($addrline, true);" jscontent="$addrline" jstcache="82" dir="ltr">Burlington, ON L7R 2G6</span>
```

is this possible?

Comment: How does google maps get the postal code wrong in the first place ?

Comment: no clue, but I know for a fact its wrong.

Comment: Post-codes change all the time and in many countries the authorities are under no obligation to publish up-to-date information. If you want to display a different postal code then you would need a better data source than that used by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to notify Google of the error.  They're pretty good about invetigating and following up these reports.

I noticed a problem when planning a trip a year or so ago.  Google maps directions was taking a rather long detour around a perfectly good section of highway.  There's a link somewhere on the maps page to notify them of problems.  I used this and they corrected the issue about a month later.  Not immediately helpful for planning the trip, but it did get the error corrected, and for everyone else, too.

Having said all that, it should definitiely be possible in Javascript to modify the DOM elements that Maps loads into your page.  It may lead to some unexpected behaviour, though.